# Recursive function with classes in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a family tree recursive function.
I have a class

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name=None,mother=None,father=None,born=None,died=None):
        self.name=name
        self.mother=mother
        self.father=father
        self.born=born
        self.died=died
    def getname(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return ' Name: ' +str(self.name)+' Born: ' +str(self.born)+' Died: ' +str(self.died)
```

And I am trying to write a family tree function

```
        def ancestor(self):
        if self.getfather() and self.getmother() == None:
            return []
        else:
            Ancestors=[]
            #Here I want to recursively call the function on the other family members, and list them all in the list Ancestors and when these are None stop the function and return the list

        return Ancestors
```

However I am new to recursion and am not sure how to write this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
def ancestors(self):
    father = self.getfather()
    mother = self.getmother()

    ancestors = []
    if father is not None:
      ancestors.append(father)
      ancestors.extend(father.ancestors())
    if mother is not None:
      ancestors.append(mother)
      ancestors.extend(mother.ancestors())

    return ancestors
```

seems like it'd work (variable/method names changed slightly to reflect what they actually do).

Note that `getfather`/`getmother` isn't a method you've shown us, I'm just assuming it's there and works.  (Though using getters doesn't seem necessary).

In the case that both `mother` and `father` are `None`, the method returns an empty list (the `ancestors` list which was never appended/extended to).

For each parent that is `not None`, the method appends that parent to the `ancestors` list and extends it with the results from calling the same `ancestors` method on that parent.

Working example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name=None, mother=None, father=None):
        self.name = name
        self.mother = mother
        self.father = father

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def ancestors(self):
        father = self.father  # or .getfather() if implemented
        mother = self.mother  # ''

        ancestors = []
        if father is not None:
            ancestors.append(father)
            ancestors.extend(father.ancestors())
        if mother is not None:
            ancestors.append(mother)
            ancestors.extend(mother.ancestors())

        return ancestors

M1 = Person("M1")
F1 = Person("F1")
C1 = Person("C1", M1, F1)

M2 = Person("M2")
F2 = Person("F2")
C2 = Person("C2", M2, F2)

C3 = Person("C3", C1, C2)

print(C1.ancestors())
print(C2.ancestors())
print(C3.ancestors())
```

Output:

```
[F1, M1]
[F2, M2]
[C2, F2, M2, C1, F1, M1]
```

The `__repr__` method just specifies the string representation for the object, otherwise the `print` statements would result in an output like

```
[<__main__.Person object at 0x000001A8F5C6FC10>, 
 <__main__.Person object at 0x000001A8F5C6FD30>]
```

instead of

```
[F1, M1]
```

Comment: I created the get functions and your approach seems very good, however I am getting a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

Comment: @KarlChristiansen I just updated the answer with example code -- maybe that helps.  From your error it sounds like your `ancestors` method is returning `None` somewhere (and `.extend(None)` will raise that error).